# Current on each winding of a solenoid and wire selection

Tags: current, inductor, wire, inductance

While I was reading an article about inductors and air core solenoids in general, I came across the term voltage per turn. Until then I thought that all of the windings of a coil are a continuous wire having the same current. But this term made me wonder that, does each turn of a coil behave like a parallel branch having the same voltage and current? Also if this is so, is the output current is equal to the sum of all the currents?

These questions are actually subsections of another main question that, if I have a  generator that generates a pulse of 800 amperes and about 10 kilovolts, then should I divide the current by the number of turns and look for wire qualification that satisfies the divided value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Practically, are those turns in series or parallel?

Comment: @PhilG well, they look like they are parallel but they continue from each other so I thought they behave like series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'volts per turn' of a winding depends on the flux linkage. In the case of a high permeability core like iron or ferrite, all turns whether large or small share essentially the same flux, so each turn has the same voltage generated across it when the flux changes.

You specifically mention air-core solenoids in your question. Here, outer turns of a multi-layer solenoid will enclose more flux, so will have a higher volts per turn due to flux changes.

Whether all turns run at the same current is a matter for how you've connected them. If all are in series, then they all share the same current. If several turns are in parallel, then they may share current unequally.

If you are simply using the solenoid to generate a static magnetic field, and have wound it from a long length of wire, then once the transients have died away, the longer outer turns will drop more DC voltage across them, as they have a higher resistance than the smaller inner turns.

Comment: I am accelerating a permanent magnet into an air core solenoid which has 257 turns  in total of two layers and wanting around 10k voltage ideally. I am just wanting to know that does the output current from the solenoid is equal to 257*I where I is the current on a turn, or does the current at that instance is equal everywhere.

Comment: If you've wound a single wire into 257 turns, all turns are therefore in series, so the terminal current is the same as the current in each turn. The wire has to be rated for your terminal current, though you can choose carefully what your rating is. Wire fails through a) over-temperature and b) mechanical breakage through Lorentz forces. If the current pulse is short enough, then you can run very high currents without heating the wire beyond its insulation breakdown temperature. For short pulses, \$I^2t\$ tends to be constant, given by the permissible temperature rise.

Comment: I would vote your answer but unfortunately my reputation is lacking. Thank you